# python psycopg2 ConnectionError: Transaction failed, failure was 'int' object does not support indexing

Tags: postgresql, psycopg2

I am using, python psycopg2 to connect to PostGreSQL and fetching some data on based on timestamp. create_date is defined as below:

```
create_date | timestamp without time zone | not null
```

My query is here

```
SELECT *                      
FROM table_name          
WHERE EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM create_date) < 1367945358;
```

But it throws an error like this, 
    ConnectionError: Transaction failed, failure was 'int' object does not support indexing

Any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, psycopg2 with pooling, expects arguments binding in tuple format in python. So I had to pass (1367945358, ) in the code. Thanks guys.